# Programmatically set the datasource for a Crystal Report on a Crystal Server via Crystal Web Services

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, crystal-reports

How can I change the data source (database server, username, password) that a Crystal report uses at runtime, running within a crystal server?

I have a crystal server and have uploaded reports that have a set datasource (SQL Server 2005 hosted on SERVER A, userA, passwordA).  I would like to schedule reports to run using a different datasource (SQL Server 2005 hosted on SERVER B, userB, passwordB) from the c# client I've written.

The c# client can schedule reports to run within the server using objects provided by the crystal webservices.
I've been using the following 3 objects:

```
BIPlatform
InfoObject
CrystalReport
```

Documentation on these objects can be found [HERE](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2/en/en/WS_SDK/wssdk_consumer/doc/wssdk_java_consumer_apiRef/allclasses-noframe.html)

Comment: Your documentation link point to Java documentation but you tagged your question as C# question ?

Answer (score 6):

1/30/2018 -Just wanted to add that you will need the CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel dll

I had the same problem, where i have a report that has MSAccess database connection and i needed to change that to SQLServer, it took 2 days to figure this out:

```
            reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            reportDocument.Load(reportFileName);
            TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = ReportClass.GetSQLTableLogOnInfo(connectionProperties.DatabaseSource, connectionProperties.DatabaseName, connectionProperties.UserName, connectionProperties.Password);
            for (int i = 0; i < reportDocument.Database.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                Table table = reportDocument.Database.Tables[i];
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
            }

     public static ConnectionInfo GetConnectionInfo(string serverName, string         databaseName, string userID, string password)
    {
        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        connectionInfo.ServerName = serverName;
        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
        connectionInfo.UserID = userID;
        connectionInfo.Password = password;
        return connectionInfo;
    }

    public static TableLogOnInfo GetSQLTableLogOnInfo(string serverName, string databaseName, string userID, string password)
    {
        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag connectionAttributes = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();
        connectionAttributes.EnsureCapacity(11);
        connectionAttributes.Add("Connect Timeout", "15");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Data Source", serverName);
        connectionAttributes.Add("General Timeout", "0");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Initial Catalog", databaseName);
        connectionAttributes.Add("Integrated Security", false);
        connectionAttributes.Add("Locale Identifier", "1033");
        connectionAttributes.Add("OLE DB Services", "-5");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Provider", "SQLOLEDB");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Tag with column collation when possible", "0");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Use DSN Default Properties", false);
        connectionAttributes.Add("Use Encryption for Data", "0");

        DbConnectionAttributes attributes = new DbConnectionAttributes();
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("Database DLL", "crdb_ado.dll"));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseName", databaseName));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseType", "OLE DB (ADO)"));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_LogonProperties", connectionAttributes));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_ServerDescription", serverName));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("SSO Enabled", false));

        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = ReportClass.GetConnectionInfo(serverName, databaseName, userID, password);
        connectionInfo.Attributes = attributes;
        connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;

        TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
        return tableLogOnInfo;
    }
```

Comment: great .. but  Arabic characters converted to [????] ... i changed Locale Identifier to 3073 .... but no action

Answer (score 2):

```
CrystalReportSource1.Report = new Report { FileName = @"C:\test.rpt" };
CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(user,pass,server,db)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get some info about the [ConnectionInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226340.aspx)

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = 
                 new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo();

myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Database";
myConnectionInfo.UserID = "Username";
myConnectionInfo.Password = "P@ssword";
```

[Programmatically Change a Crystal Reports datasource location](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4029) - in VB but you can use one of the online translation tools to convert from VB to C#:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/
http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/
http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: The ConnectionInfo class is not exposed by the crystal web service.  It's a class contained in the assembly CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll.  I need a solution that uses the web service objects because I believe this is the only way I can interact with the reports as they are hosted on a Crystal Web Server.