# Crystal Reports 2008 and TLS 1.2 - bulk updating data sources

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, tls1.2

We have a SQL Server 2014 SP3 instance that is currently running on TLS 1.1. We are also using Crystal Reports 2008 for our reporting.

We are currently testing upgrading our SQL Server instances to TLS 1.2, and we've run into the issue where older versions of Crystal Reports does not run on TLS 1.2 servers.

Our reports currently use OLE DB connections to our SQL server, and I found that changing to an ODBC (RDO) connection works fine.

Now - the issue is that we have hundreds of reports, and manually opening each one and updating the connection string is just not feasible. I know there are tools out there for this purpose, but we're not really keen on spending money on a once-off thing.

Is there perhaps some other sneaky way we can do this, perhaps through C# via a nuget package?

Thanks!

Comment: I subsequently found that OLE DB does work, but the SQL Native Client driver does not work. OLE DB with the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically set the datasource for a Crystal Report on a Crystal Server via Crystal Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074557/programmatically-set-the-datasource-for-a-crystal-report-on-a-crystal-server-via)

Comment: Thanks for the assist @siggemannen! That article provided the base from which I managed to put a C# app together that will do the update.

Comment: Great, if you have time, feel free to answer your own question with some code, or at least point to which answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This tool can handle bulk datasource update to TLS 1.2: http://r-tag.com/Pages/CRDataSource.aspx